# Get all currently logged users in ASPNet Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a ASP.Net Core Web Application secured by plain cookie authentication.

I want to know if there is way of getting all currently logged users in my application.

I searched on Stack Overflow and Google without success and I am starting to wonder if this is feasible natively.

Comment: I would appreciate if someone commented on the close votes.. I undertand this quesiton as sucint, not just broad.. It is clear what's being asked and it doesn't have multiple answers

Comment: Cookies are stored locally on the client, thus I don't see how you could get this information from your server code... I would probably add that feature directly in the auth api OR maintain a list of connected users in the cache.